# Trying to use ParseSwift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, parse-server

In an iOS app using `SwiftUI` and communicating with a Parse-Server I am trying to make use of `ParseSwift`, following the information found [here](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/blob/0ac301b567d2de31ce7f5952a69038c851439e99/ParseSwift.playground/Pages/11%20-%20LiveQuery.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift#L33-L86).

But I see nothing happening (even if I make some changes on the server), other than the display switching at the beginning from:

```
"Not subscribed to a query"
```

to:

```
"Subscribed to query!"
```

In other words, I am not really sure what is working and what is not.

This is the code for the relevant view:

```
import SwiftUI
import ParseSwift

struct OnLineView: View {
    @ObservedObject var subscription = onlineQuery.subscribe!
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if subscription.subscribed != nil {
                Text("Subscribed to query!")
            } else if subscription.unsubscribed != nil {
                Text("Unsubscribed from query!")
            } else if let event = subscription.event {
                // THE EXECUTION FLOW NEVER REACHES THIS POINT.

                //: This is how you register to receive notifications of events related to your LiveQuery.
                switch event.event {

                case .entered(let object):
                    Text("Entered with TITLE: \(object.TITLE!)")
                case .left(let object):
                    Text("Left with TITLE: \(object.TITLE!)")
                case .created(let object):
                    Text("Created with TITLE: \(object.TITLE!)")
                case .updated(let object):
                    Text("Updated with TITLE: \(object.TITLE!)")
                case .deleted(let object):
                    Text("Deleted with TITLE: \(object.TITLE!)")
                default:
                    Text("Default-event !!!!")
                }
            } else {
                Text("Not subscribed to a query")
            }

            Spacer()

            Text("Update MyClassUnit in Parse Dashboard to see changes here")

            Button(action: {
                try? onlineQuery.unsubscribe()
            }, label: {
                Text("Unsubscribe")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .cornerRadius(20.0)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
            })
        }
    }
}

struct OnLineView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OnLineView()
    }
}
```

Beside, this is the side part of the relevant code:

```
//: Create your own value typed ParseObject.
struct MyClassUnit: ParseObject {
    //: These are required for any Object.
    var objectId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var ACL: ParseACL?

    //: Your own properties.
    var TITLE: String?

    //: Custom initializer.
    init(title: String) {
        self.TITLE = title
    }
}

var onlineQuery = MyClassUnit.query()
```

Though I have some experience with `SwiftUI` and Parse-Server, this the first time I use `ParseSwift`; so I may well be missing some basic point.

At the end I want to be able to catch in my view some information of what is on my server DB.

I hope somebody with an experience of `ParseSwift` will be able to point out some issue in what I did or give me a hint on where to look at in order to make some progress.

....
I haven't touched my parse-server at this point.
I saw in the documentation that I need to set up the `LiveQuery` server. But reading further didn't make it clear what I have to do.

Does this mean I have to perform some modifications in the settings of my parse-server? Or is it about something different?
Practically speaking I don't know what to do about this. So this may be the issue.

This piece from the server side may also be useful:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri,
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY,
  filesAdapter: "@parse/s3-files-adapter",
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
  publicServerURL: process.env.PARSE_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL,
  appName: 'TheApp',
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  emailAdapter: {
    module: '@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      fromAddress: 'special@rmail.com',
      domain: 'xtkd.net',
      apiKey: process.env.EML_ADAPTER_KEY,
    }
  },
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ['CollectionMain', 'CollectionSecond']
  }
});
```

Another piece of relevant information. This what I can see in the logs:

```
... app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
... app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
... app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
... app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
... app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
... app[web.1]: parse-server-example running on port 27596.
... app[web.1]: info: Parse LiveQuery Server starts running
... heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

And this is the package.json I am using:

```
{
    .....
    "dependencies": {
      "@parse/s3-files-adapter": "^1.4.0",
      "@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter": "^1.0.3",
      "aws-sdk": "^2.637.0",
      "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
      "body-parser": "1.19.0",
      "ejs": "^3.0.1",
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "parse": "~1.8.0",
      "parse-server": "^3.9.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "engines": {
      "node": ">=4.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is something missing on your Parse Server settings. Could you share the current settings?

Comment: @Davi Macêdo. I edited the post and added some server information at the end, please have a look and let me know if you want to know something else.

Comment: You are missing live query setup: https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#live-queries

Comment: I have changed the server settings, but there is still something I am missing because it is yet not working.

Comment: No events are firing? Would you mind to share the new settings and little bit more information on how you are deploying Parse Server?

Comment: Indeed there are hints showing up in the logs (I made an update of the post) and this is what I am currently investigating.

Comment: After searching the net, I suspect I may not be using the correct version of some packages, so I also shown the package.json file in the post.

Comment: This is what I started from to set my parse-server:
https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example.git

Comment: Do you have a single process running parse server or multiple ones (maybe via docker or pm2)?

Comment: I don't use docker of pm2. My parse-server is running on Heroku. As far as I know there is only a single process running parse server. The DB used to be on mLab, and is now on Atlas.

Comment: Does the "Subscribed to query!" show up?

Comment: Yes it shows up inside the iOS app, as written in my post. Is this what you mean? By the way are the messages in the logs OK. I noticed that the same messages also appear in a working app.

Comment: There must be something fundamentally wrong in what I do. I added a comment inside the post: "THE EXECUTION FLOW NEVER REACHES THIS POINT.". The mistake may be basic, but at this point, any action on the server side has no whatsoever effect on the iOS app side.

Comment: Would you mind to share your query and also how you are doing in order to test the events?

Comment: In order to test the events I add a value to  the collection on the server side. And I look for something happening inside the mobile app or in the Xcode debugging console.

Comment: How are you adding the value? Parse Dashboard, API, directly in the database? Is it connecting to the same Parse Server instance?

Comment: I simply refresh the web page of my app. I you look at the code in function topDisplayFunc(), you will see that when the page is visited a new value is automatically added to SampleCollection. (Cf. my other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67650391/how-to-make-parseserver-work-with-parseswift)

Comment: Maybe the value is being added before the subscription completes? Could you try to add a new value using the dashboard?

Comment: "the value is being added before the subscription completes".
This is highly unlikely, even impossible: I start the iOS app an confirm that the message "Subscribed to query!" shows up. And then a few seconds or tens of seconds later I refresh the web page generating a new value in the DB.

Comment: I have also tried to add a value using the dashboard, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if your Swift project is connecting to the exact same Parse Server instance of your web project and dashboard. Let's say you have multiple instances running on heroku. Even if they are connecting to the same mongodb, the events that happen on one of the instances do not fire events to the clients subscribed in the other instances. In order to that happen, the easiest way would be spinning up a redis server and settings `redisUrl` under your Parse Server `liveQuery` options, as you can see in here: https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#scalability