# How to make ParseServer work with ParseSwift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, parse-server

I have an iOS app using SwiftUI.
Then making use of ParseSwift, I am trying to make it work with a Parse-Server. For some reasons things don't work out. If someone can shed some light on the issue that would be very helpful.

First, here is the code for the server:

```
const express = require('express');
const ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
const path = require('path');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;
const args = process.argv || [];
const test = args.some(arg => arg.includes('jasmine'));

const databaseUri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

const config = {
  databaseURI: databaseUri,
  cloud: __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY,
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
  publicServerURL: process.env.PARSE_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL,
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ['SampleCollection', 'MainCollection'],
  },
};

const app = express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
const mountPath = '/parse';

if (!test) {
  const api = new ParseServer(config);
  app.use(mountPath, api);
}

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  topDisplayFunc("index", res);
});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
if (!test) {
  const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
  httpServer.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
  });
  // This will enable the Live Query real-time server
  ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
}

module.exports = {
  app,
  config,
};


function topDisplayFunc(displayPage, response) {
  MongoClient.connect(databaseUri, {useUnifiedTopology: true}, 
    function(err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var db = client.db();
    
    let theCollection = db.collection('SampleCollection');
    theCollection.countDocuments().then((count) => {
        theCollection.insertOne({number: count + 1}, function (err) {
          if(err) throw err;

          db.collection('SampleCollection', function (err, collection) {
            collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
              if(err) throw err;
      
              response.render('pages/' + displayPage, {
                dataArray: items
              });
      
              client.close();
            });
          });
        });
    });
  });
}
```

And following is the relevant code in the iOS app:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    .......
    ParseSwift.initialize(applicationId: parseAppId,
                          clientKey: parseKey,
                          serverURL: URL(string: parseServer)!)
    
    return true
}
```

and then:

```
//  ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import ParseSwift


.......
var onlineQuery = SampleCollection.query(["number" > 5])

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    .......

    var body: some View {
        .......
        ZStack{}.sheet(isPresented: $showingOnLine) {
            OnLineView()
                //.environmentObject(langType)
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the code for the view where I expect something to happen, when I perform some operation on the server related to the SampleCollection, but nothing happens.

```
import SwiftUI
import ParseSwift

struct OnLineView: View {
    @ObservedObject var subscription = onlineQuery.subscribe!
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if subscription.subscribed != nil {
                Text("Subscribed to query!")
            } else if subscription.unsubscribed != nil {
                Text("Unsubscribed from query!")
            } else if let event = subscription.event {

                //: This is how you register to receive notifications of events related to your LiveQuery.
                switch event.event {

                case .entered(let object):
                    Text("Entered EVENT: ")
                case .left(let object):
                    Text("Left EVENT: ")
                case .created(let object):
                    Text("Created EVENT: ")
                case .updated(let object):
                    Text("Updated EVENT: ")
                case .deleted(let object):
                    Text("Deleted EVENT: ")
                default:
                    Text("Default-event !!!!")
                }
            } else {
                Text("Not subscribed to a query")
            }

            Spacer()

            Text("Update DATA in Parse Dashboard to see changes here")

            Button(action: {
                try? onlineQuery.unsubscribe()
            }, label: {
                Text("Unsubscribe")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .cornerRadius(20.0)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
            })
        }
    }
}

struct OnLineView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OnLineView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try with `SampleCollection.query("number" > 5)` instead of `SampleCollection.query(["number" > 5])`?

Comment: I had this before and just tried it again. I makes no difference at all. I had also tried SampleCollection.query() to get all, but also without success.

Comment: If you run the query a single time (without subscription), does it return the data? I am wondering if your CLP/ACL setup allows the data to be read.

Comment: Your tip may be good, but how can I try this? If I comment out the line containing "subscription = onlineQuery.subscribe!". It does not seem to work. Do you have something else in mind?

Comment: You can use the `find()` function and log the result.

Comment: That was a good tip, because using find() I am able to retrieve the data in the online DB. That still does not explain why I do not get any event when using a subscription. And beside I would like to retrieve all the data, not only those with ("number" > 5). I tried to replace ("number" > 5) by (); but with no success.

Comment: I'd suggest you to open a ticket in Parse Swift repo. The maintainers of the project can help you to figure it out.